# How to filter customer collection by custom field added by db_schema xml file to customer_entity table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, collection, customer-collection

I added 'custom_field' to 'customer_entity' table by using 'db_schema.xml' file and need to save 'some value' in it then I wanted to filter the collection by 'custom_field' value. How can I achieve this ? When I use the below code.

```
$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create();
$customerData = $customer->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('custom_field',array('neq'=>'cleared'))->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')->load();
```

I am getting this error : `The "custom_field" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.`

Comment: Hi @shankar, Did you try the filter by using addFieldToFilter like below:

$customer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('custom_field',array('neq'=>'cleared'))->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')->load();

Comment: Hi @Magedivine I tried it but no luck. let me try again

Comment: This was helped me : https://gist.github.com/mrkhoa99/f4582535d6124709885521be185894c4

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `addFieldToFilter` instead of `addAttributeToFilter` because you are working with the database table field rather than a customer attribute.

**Please try it once:**

```
$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create();
$customerData = $customer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('custom_field',array('neq'=>'cleared'))->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')->load();
```